# Searching a TextField and IntField together seperated by an AND condition In Lucene

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I have indexed my documents as:

```
doc.add(new IntField("ID", id, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("First_Name", First_Name, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("Last_Name", Last_Name, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("Address", add, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("City", city, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("State", state, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new IntField("Zip_Code", zip, Field.Store.YES));
```

Where id, FirstName, city, add, state, zip are variables that store the values to be indexed.

I want to search on the indexes as **"ID:someValue AND First_Name:SomeValue"**
but since the query parsers for int field and string field are different, I am unable to do so.

I am searching the document as:

```
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchQuery);
TopScoreDocCollector collector=TopScoreDocCollector.create(LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH); 
indexSearcher.search(query, collector );
```

and for integer values as:

```
query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(field, searchTerm, searchTerm , true, true);        
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);
indexSearcher.search(query, collector );
```

How can I use a single Query Parser, such that it can handle both text and Numeric values?  How do I search for such a query using a single query?

Comment: Can you show some example input (`searchQuery`)?

Comment: @user1071777 searchQuery is based upon the user input
it can be as: **First_Name: {Aida TO Carmen} AND Last_Name:Smith** 

searchTerm is an Integer value corresponding to the ID field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.

First, what I would most recommend in this case, is perhaps you don't need those `IntField`s at all.  Zip codes and IDs are usually not treated as numbers.  They are identifiers that happen to be comprised of digits.  If your zip code is 23456, that doesn't imply you reside in the 23,456th zip code.  It's just a string of arbitrary digits.  If it wouldn't be useful to search a field using a numeric range, you should probably just make it a `StringField` (or `TextField`).

If you really want it to be a, `IntField`, though, you can just skip the parser.  Just use the APIs to construct your query:

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(new BooleanClause(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("ID", myIdValue, myIdValue, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
query.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("First_Name", myNameValue)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Comment: I am using **Lucene 5.1.0** , so this doesn't work for me. 

query.add(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("ID", myIdValue, myIdValue, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

 gives an error.  It says the function **add** to be undefined

Comment: add is undefined for the type query. Eclipse IDE asks to typecast it to the type booleanQuery

Comment: Ah, right. Wasn't paying very close attention when writing this to be honest.  Hopefully that works better.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.  Tested to be sure, the code in it's current state works fine.  Maybe you're viewing a cached page or something.  Really, though, is it that hard to work out the issue?  Eclipse warns you that the query needs to be a `BooleanQuery` instead of `Query`, right?  So declare it a `BooleanQuery` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works and serves my purpose well.!